# What could be causing my CursorLoader to miss updates?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-contentprovider, android-loader

I have a loader in a fragment that essentially "counts" the rows in the database, using a content provider backed by an sqlite database. I also have a background thread adding/removing rows in the database. The service is started from the same activity as the one my fragment is attached to.

The behavior I see is the following:

- Service successfully adds/removes rows
- The content provider notifies of the change by calling `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` (this is verified by log statements)
- The fragment does not see the change unless I call a force-refresh on the loader (`getLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID).forceLoad()`)

Here's how I update the content in a separate service:

```
// inserting values...
final ContentValues cv = generateContentValues();
getContentResolver().insert(ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI, cv);

// and elsewhere in the code, deleting values...
getContentResolver().delete(ItemEntry.buildItemUri(id), null, null);
```

Here's where I create the loader:

```
public static String[] ITEM_COLUMNS = new String[] { ItemEntry._ID };

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateLoader called");

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onCreateLoader", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            ITEM_COLUMNS,
            null,
            null,
            null);
}


@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "found " + data.getCount() + " items", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    processDataCount(data.getCount());
}
```

I've tried creating the loader with `null` as the projection, which should return all the columns, but there is no difference. Essentially the only way I see changes to the data is when I call `forceLoad()` on the loader.

Any ideas? I'm not even sure where to start. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ARRGH, it's always something simple!

I had forgotten to `setNotificationUri` on my return cursor from `query` in my data provider:

```
    retCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return retCursor;
```

Be careful copy/pasting out there, folks!